# QGIS digitizing points and autofilling attribute value from persistent form

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, digitizing, qgis-customization

I need to manually digitize elevation point maps. (using QGIS 3.24)
Instead of the default QGIS method ( enter point + enter height), I would like to inverse the sequence:
specify the height and then digitize all points with the height automatically set in the attribute table.

I suppose this should be possibly with a persistent form where I'd enter the desired value and subsequently activate the edit/add point function.

Is such a thing possible in QGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the non-modal/modeless form was easier than expected

With QTdesigner I made a crude form with a height textbox, +button, -button and modify button.

once all points digitized, I now select the points of a same height, click the modify button on the form and continue.

btw: digitizing points and heights simultaneously felt slower.

```
from qgis.PyQt import uic
frm = uic.loadUi("./tools/Hupdate.ui")
def cmd_bt_up():
    frm.tb_Hg.setPlainText(  str(int(frm.tb_Hg.toPlainText()) + 1))
    
def cmd_bt_down():
    frm.tb_Hg.setPlainText( str(int(frm.tb_Hg.toPlainText()) - 1))

def cmd_bt_set():
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName( 'points_pt' )[0]
    layer.startEditing()
    for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
        feat["Heigth"] = frm.tb_Hg.toPlainText()
        layer.updateFeature(feat)    
        
    layer.commitChanges()        

    frm.bt_up.clicked.connect( cmd_bt_up)
    frm.bt_down.clicked.connect( cmd_bt_down)
    frm.bt_set.clicked.connect( cmd_bt_set)
    frm.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Layer Properties
2. Attributes form
3. Drag and drop designer. Drag your elevation field to Form layout
4. Set a default value

All points you add will get the value. Digitize then change the default value when you need other values.

[image]

Comment: Thank Bera and Erik for your replies

I tried the defaults value method ( and last entered values)

It works, but it is not flowing enough - I'd need to modify that value regularly.

I've been searching to get just this option as a "non-modal" form, but haven't found that yet.

for clarity: I come from an arcgis/view background. Non-modal does not seem to be in Qgis vocabulary .   By non-modal or modeless, I mean a form which does not impose focus, other parts of qgis can be used (as points digitizing)

Comment: The closest I've come:  
1) set the default value to a project variable f.e. Def_Height  
  
2) using the python console (which is non-modal), I modify the variable using command  
QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(), 'Def_Height','91')  
  
3) carry on adding points, going back to 2) when needed  
  
 admitted it is crude, but workable in Qgis lingo, what would non-modal be? thanks again for your help

Comment: You could create a small python script/function to update for example all points without heights with some value. And call with `setheight(150)` after you've added a number of points. Or update selected points

Answer (score 3):

In the settings, in the submenu `digitizing` you may tell QGIS to reuse the last entered value for attributes.

[image]

Comment: Danke Erik 
please see my comment on Bera reply.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came to, based on the suggestion by Bera

1. set an project variable f.e. Def_Height
2. set the default value to that project variable in the layer properties
3. using the python console (which is non-modal), I modify the variable to the desired value using command
   QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(), 'Def_Height','91')
4. carry on adding points, going back to 2) when needed

a further slight improvement:
using autoit3, I made two scripts to increase and decrease the variable by 1 (-1)
those 2 scripts are linked to hotkeys on my keyboard
I can add points with the set value, hit a hotkey and continue with the next value up or down. without having to open properties or manually entering commands.

As stated, it is crude, but works.

best regards